# Search data in sql on behalf of list of parameters ,

Tags: sql

Hi All i am unable to create a query in sql  i want to get all employee who's contain the product which i passed in parameter

Ex, i if passed product id 11,12 then its should be return only DeliveryBoyId1 and 2 and if passed the product id 11 then its should be return only DeliveryBoyId  1,2,3  and if i passed productid 11,12,16 then its should return 0 record because  there is no delivery boy assigned the product id 11,12,16

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your table is called so I'm calling it `dbo.Delivery`. Try this out:

```
;with CTE as (
  select distinct DeliveryBoyId --get all the boys who delivered product 11
  from dbo.Delivery
  where ProductId = 11

  union all --combine the above results with the below

  select distinct DeliveryBoyId --get all the boys who delivered product 12
  from dbo.Delivery
  where ProductId = 12
)
select DeliveryBoyId
from CTE
group by DeliveryBoyId
having count(1) = 2 --get all the boys who appear twice in the above table, once for each product
```

If you want to match additional products, you can add to the `CTE` section for other product IDs.

If you want a single solution for any number of products, you can use this instead (which may be a little less readable but more concise and easier to maintain):

```
select DeliveryBoyId
from (
  select distinct DeliveryBoyId, ProductId
  from dbo.Delivery
  where ProductId in (11, 12)
 ) s
group by DeliveryBoyId
having count(1) = 2 --number matches number of products you need to match
```

Comment: Thank for your reply , i tried to used this query but my requirement not full fill  , i want to get only those delivery boy id  who has assign the  both product id 11 and 12 if i passed the product id in(11,12) then  its  return me  delivery boy  who has assign  product id 11 either 12

Comment: Do you have a product table?

Comment: Updated the answer. I am using what's called a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which allows you to gather some data into a table that I am calling `CTE` and use it in the next statement. This is in lieu of creating a separate temp table

Comment: Also added a nested table example, which may be a but more difficult to read but is the more concise solution

Comment: Great, go ahead and mark this as the answer when you get a chance for others to find